# Adding type for useRef on ScrollView react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native

Looking to create a ref to a ScrollView component like so: `const ref = useRef<ScrollView>(null);` (or something to this effect) essentially I need access to the `flashScrollIndicators` method like this:

```
<ScrollView
  ref={ref}
  onContentSizeChange={() => ref?.current?.flashScrollIndicators()}>
  {children}
</ScrollView>
```

The code does work in my app however typescripts definitions for ScrollView doesn't seem to include flashScrollIndicators?
I'm getting `Property 'flashScrollIndicators' does not exist on type 'ScrollView'.ts(2339)` looking through the types I can see SectionList and Flatlist so unsure if this is an bug with the definitions or just me not using it properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some research, I couldn't find any official documentation or blog post with the correct solution but declaring the ref using ScrollView itself worked for me. So you can do something like:

```
const scrollViewRef = React.useRef<ScrollView>(null);
```

And then autocomplete will take care of the rest, hope it helps!

Comment: Appreciate the response, unfortunately thats something I've already tried (if you re-read the question you'll see i mentioned that on the first line), the typing for ScrollView doesn't seem to contain the flashScrollIndicators function, for now I'm just `@ts-ignore`'ing the call as I know it works

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me.

Comment: This was previously not working, but I've accepted now as the official declaration file for ScrollView has been updated since this answer was submitted so it does now :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the `flashscrollindicators` does exist on ScrollView in documentation (and works in app) https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#flashscrollindicators I assume this is bug in type definition.

I think the cleanest solution is to define your own ScrollViewRef using intersection.

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export type ScrollViewRef = ScrollView & {
    flashScrollIndicators: () => void;
};
```

then use this type to define the ref

```
const scrollViewRef = React.useRef<ScrollViewRef | null>(null);
```